# Output are different when i convert date to utc format in java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript

Java code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String aDateString = "1993-06-15 09:35:00";
Date date = sdf.parse(aDateString);
System.out.println("reference date:"+date.getTime());

long dtDate1=Date.UTC(1993,06,15,9,35,00);
System.out.println(dtDate1);
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var d = Date.UTC(1993,06,15,09,35,00,00);  
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=d;
}
</script>
```

When i use java code to convert date in UTC format it gives me the following output:

```
reference date:727070700000
60700959300000
```

When i use javascript code to convert date in UTC format it gives me the following output:

```
742728900000
```

Why both output are different? 
Give me the solution to convert date in UTC format in java and javascript, so that both output are similar.

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");` M is for month in year while m is for minute in hour.

Comment: Yes, M is for month in year while m is for minute in hour

Comment: You define "yyyy-**mm**-dd" in the first code extract

Comment: Oh, its my mistake. please consider M for month and m for minute

Comment: There is no static `Date.UTC()` method in Java, your first code extract won't compile

Comment: because java !== JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working java code snippet that gives a reasonable value for the UTC time (using the deprecated Date.UTC(int,int,int,int,int,int) method.
Also note that month is zero based so that 5 = June (I think the same is true for javascript).

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String aDateString = "1993-06-15 09:35:00";
        Date date = sdf.parse(aDateString);
        System.out.println("reference date:"+date.getTime());

        long dtDate1= Date.UTC(93, 05, 15, 9, 35, 00);
        System.out.println(dtDate1);
        long diff = (dtDate1 - date.getTime())/3600000;
        System.out.println("hours diff =" + diff );

    }
```

Here is the output:

> reference date:740154900000
>
> 740136900000
>
> hours diff =-5

Answer (score 0):

`Date.UTC` is deprecated to avoid using it, try something like:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.set(1993, 6, 15, 9, 35, 0);
long dtDate2 = cal.getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println(dtDate2);
```

If you really want to use Date.UTC, then you have to realise the year section is from 1900, therefore you need yo use the following:

```
Date.UTC(1993 - 1900, 06, 15, 9, 35, 00);
```

This is specified in the Java API for Date:

> A year y is represented by the integer y - 1900.

Source: [Date (Java Platform SE 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)